# ¿Como guardar imagen en django en una carpeta cuyo nombre sea el id del objeto guardado?

Tags: django, django-models

Estoy trabajando en un sistema donde hay inmobiliarias, las cuales publican inmuebles y estos tienen fotos de portada. Necesito guardar las imagenes de portada de los inmuebles en una ruta similar a esta: `/media/id_de_inmobiliaria/id_inmueble/portada.jpg`. El codigo que implemente para esto es el siguiente:

**settings.py**

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

**models.py**

```
def portada_inmueble_path(instance, file_name):
    print('ID', instance.pk) //El id o pk en este punto es None
    return '{}/{}/{}'.format(
        instance.inmobiliaria.id,
        instance.pk,
        file_name)


class Inmueble(models.Model):
...
portada = models.ImageField(upload_to=portada_inmueble_path, blank=True,
                                null=True, max_length=99)
...
```

**signals.py**

```
@receiver(signals.pre_save, sender=Inmueble)
def inmueble_pre_save(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    new_file = instance.portada
    try:
        old_file = Inmueble.objects.get(pk=instance.pk).portada
        if not old_file == new_file:
            if os.path.isfile(old_file.path):
                os.remove(old_file.path)
    except:
        pass
```

El problema es claro, `como el objeto todavia no fue guardado no tiene un id`, por lo tanto me crea una carpeta "None" donde me guarda las portadas. Como puedo hacer para obtener el id del objeto para crear la carpeta y guardar la imagen en esa ruta? 
Muchas gracias, en caso de necesitar alguna otra porcion de codigo pueden pedirla.

Answer (score 1):

Si la clave primary key es autoincremental, no hay forma de saber el id antes de llamar al metodo save, puesto que de esto se encarga la base de datos, no django. [leído en la documentación](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/instances/#auto-incrementing-primary-keys)

Una opción que podrías plantear, es por ejemplo crear primero el inmueble, y una vez que tienes su id, añadir la portada.

Comment: Gracias, en realidad quería evitar eso porque puede traer más errores.. Pero es una opción